# Generate variable with odd and even labels

Tags: stata

I have a variable `num` with values `1-10`.

I would like to create a new variable `type` with values `odd` or `even`:

```
generate type = odd if inlist(num, 1,3,5,7,9)
```

Questions:

1. What is the cleanest way to also label even numbers?
2. Could I use a negation somewhere and keep the command all in one line?

Answer (score 0):

The code you provide is not valid syntax:

```
clear
set obs 10
generate num = _n

generate type = odd if inlist(num, 1,3,5,7,9)
odd not found
r(111);
```

You could get what you want with:

```
generate type = "odd" if inlist(num, 1,3,5,7,9)
```

And you can do both at the same time using the `cond()` function:

```
generate type = cond(inlist(num, 1,3,5,7,9), "odd", "even")
```

However, having this variable as a *string* will be of limited value for later use.

You could subsequently use the `encode` command to create a new variable of numeric type:

```
encode type, generate(type2)

list

     +--------------------+
     | num   type   type2 |
     |--------------------|
  1. |   1    odd     odd |
  2. |   2   even    even |
  3. |   3    odd     odd |
  4. |   4   even    even |
  5. |   5    odd     odd |
     |--------------------|
  6. |   6   even    even |
  7. |   7    odd     odd |
  8. |   8   even    even |
  9. |   9    odd     odd |
 10. |  10   even    even |
     +--------------------+
```

Although seemingly identical, `type` and `type2` variables are indeed of a different type:

```
list, nolabel

     +--------------------+
     | num   type   type2 |
     |--------------------|
  1. |   1    odd       2 |
  2. |   2   even       1 |
  3. |   3    odd       2 |
  4. |   4   even       1 |
  5. |   5    odd       2 |
     |--------------------|
  6. |   6   even       1 |
  7. |   7    odd       2 |
  8. |   8   even       1 |
  9. |   9    odd       2 |
 10. |  10   even       1 |
     +--------------------+
```

---

This is how you can do it with `type` being a *numeric* variable:

```
generate type = mod(num, 2)

list

     +------------+
     | num   type |
     |------------|
  1. |   1      1 |
  2. |   2      0 |
  3. |   3      1 |
  4. |   4      0 |
  5. |   5      1 |
     |------------|
  6. |   6      0 |
  7. |   7      1 |
  8. |   8      0 |
  9. |   9      1 |
 10. |  10      0 |
     +------------+
```

You then create the value label and attach it to the variable `type`:

```
label define numlab 0 "even" 1 "odd"
label values type numlab

list

     +------------+
     | num   type |
     |------------|
  1. |   1    odd |
  2. |   2   even |
  3. |   3    odd |
  4. |   4   even |
  5. |   5    odd |
     |------------|
  6. |   6   even |
  7. |   7    odd |
  8. |   8   even |
  9. |   9    odd |
 10. |  10   even |
     +------------+
```

If you only want the odd numbers labeled you can simply do:

```
label define numlab 1 "odd"
```

If you later change your mind and want to add a label for even numbers:

```
label define numlab 0 "even", add
```

Answer (score 0):

When your command has been run, the value of type for the odd numbers is "odd" and the value for the even numbers is "", that is a missing string.
You could tag the even numbers using

```
replace type = "even" if type==""
```

I cannot think of a way to keep it all in one line, since you have to both generate the variable and fill in two different string values.

If you could use a numeric variable (I name it flag) as your type variable, you could try this:

```
gen flag = mod(num,2)
```

This will flag the odd numbers as 1 and the even numbers as 0. You could then create a label for the flag variable, if you need to display its values as "odd" and "even".